# Error : Failed to connect to api.quickblox.com port 443

Tags: php, api, quickblox

I am using quickblox api for video chat.

I have used php code which given on quickblox site.

I have follow below steps.

1. Create new App from Admin of admin.quickblox.com.
2. Change the code of file with my AppId, Username, Password.
3. Run the PHP file and get below error.

**Error**

> > stringForSignature: application_id=40546&auth_key=uDzRGCpp6E7pnQg&nonce=16841×tamp=1462881056&user[login]=tatva167&user[password]=tatva167
> >
> > postBody: application_id=****&auth_key=******&nonce=***&signature=****&user%5Blogin%5D=****&user%5Bpassword%5D=****
> >
> > Failed to connect to api.quickblox.com port 443: Timed out(7)

Sample code: [Click here](http://pastebin.com/DTPQ7w02)

**Question:**

Any one have idea about this API then please help me to resolve error.

If anyone have knowledge then please provide steps to run and how to load video chat of quickblox on my PHP based site.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your network problem. Ask your provider or system administrator. I can connect to host api.quickblox.com to port 443 normally:

```
$ telnet api.quickblox.com 443
Trying 52.6.217.255...
Connected to api.quickblox.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]

telnet> quit
Connection closed.
$
```